# Is it possible/useful to create core soreness?

Tags: workout, recovery, abdominals, muscle-soreness, core

I workout my core and my abs everyday for a year now and, even on heavy workout days I have never experienced core soreness.

To be complete, I have felt abs soreness for a couple of minutes, but never a soreness lastings 1-2 days after a workout like for biceps, calves, gluts, and so on.

Is there exercices/workouts able to give that result is the whole core? Is it even useful?

Comment: My Abs and lower back are very sore right now. So it is very much possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to experience delayed onset muscle soreness (DOMS) in the core muscles. Commonly used core exercises like crunches, often do not cause DOMS, but this shouldn't be taken as indicating that they aren't effective. Soreness is not a prerequisite for muscle growth or an accurate measure of workout effectiveness.[1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21270317)

As for core exercises that will cause soreness, anything that involves greater eccentric forces than concentric is likely to cause soreness. An example of this is swinging from one horizontal bar to another, known as a lache in parkour, which requires strong eccentric contractions of the abdominals and hip flexors to arrest momentum when landing on the second bar.[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KokYrZDpx0A)